# jquery ajax should call function

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

jquery ajax should call testing(propertyLevelId) function.

```
function name(roleId) {
$.ajax({
    url: '../UserManagement/GetRoleLevel' + '/?roleId=' + roleId,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    //async: false,
    success: function (result) {
        $.each(result, function (key, value) {
            alert(value.Value);
            propertyLevelId = value.Value;
        testing(propertyLevelId);//It doesnt call the function
    },
    complete: function () { },
    error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
});    
}


function testing(propertyLevelId) {
    alert(propertyLevelId);
}
```

Comment: It does call the function … unless it errors first, but you haven't told us what it does do, told us how you are checking for errors, or shown us the data you are working with.

Comment: Try to explain more what is happening....does it reach the looop for example? Do you get the alerts that you specify on the first line in the foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your JavaScript console, you should see a syntax error, as your ajax block is incomplete. You never finish the anonymous function you're passing into `each` and the closing paren and semi on the `each` call:

```
success: function (result) {
    $.each(result, function (key, value) {
        alert(value.Value);
        propertyLevelId = value.Value;
    testing(propertyLevelId);//It doesnt call the function
    // ===> here <===
},
```

It helps if you consistently indent your code, so you can see those kinds of typos more easily.

Here's a fixed version:

```
function name(roleId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../UserManagement/GetRoleLevel' + '/?roleId=' + roleId,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        //async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $.each(result, function (key, value) {
                alert(value.Value);
                propertyLevelId = value.Value;
                testing(propertyLevelId);//It doesnt call the function
            });
        },
        complete: function () { },
        error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
    });    
}
```

As a side note, unless you're declaring `propertyLevelId` somewhere in an enclosing scope that you haven't shown (I'm not talking about the argument to `testing` with the same name, I'm talking about the variable you use in your anonymous `success` function), you're falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).